# AForge: How to make Hue/Lightness/Saturation effect like Photoshop

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I am working on a project where implemented AForge and want to apply hue/saturation/lightness effect.

I've tried on existing AForge sequence filters i did not get result like PhotoShop.
Which/what filter combination should I use?

```cs
FiltersSequence filter = new FiltersSequence(
  new BrightnessCorrection(b),
  new SaturationCorrection(s),
  new ContrastCorrection(c)
 );

pictureBox2.Image = filter.Apply((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image);
```

Comment: Photoshop uses complex algorythms to calculate the outcome do you think the basw implementation in c# will provide you everything photoshop can do?
also you should be a little more specific when you say "like photoshop" cause the last time i checked there was more than one way to modify brightness etc in photoshop

Comment: @DenisSchaf, sure Photoshop uses complex algorythms to calculate it. Actualy I don't need %100 quality like PS. I am asking it is possible to make this with Aforge's existing method at least?